# Run ssh-agent 24/7 using keychain?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent, node.js

I have a Node.js script that requires ssh-agent to be running 24/7 on my Ubuntu server. I installed [keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) and put `eval 'keychain --eval id_rsa` into my `~/.bash_profile`, but that only runs when I ssh into the machine.

Is there a way to have the ssh-agent run 24/7 using keychain?

EDIT: If there is a way to have the ssh-agent run only at certain times of the day (e.g. 4pm-7pm), that would be better. But 24/7 would be fine too.

Comment: Why not just have a cron job that starts it at the given time and stops it when necessary?